# How to allow a slave node run parallel jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have setup Jenkins master and slave. The job will run on the slave node. But if I trigger another job and the second job has to wait until the first one finished. Is there possible for me to run multiple jobs in one slave node together?

Comment: Increase the number of executors for that slave in Jenkins administration -> Manage Nodes section

Comment: Ok, it works. Could you give an answer then I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increase the number of executors for that slave in Jenkins administration -> Manage Nodes section